# HTML link not working

Tags: html, css

I'm totally lost on this one.  I have two pages:

```
http://174.129.230.175/
http://174.129.230.175/?page_id=819
```

On the first page, the privacy policy link is not working, but on the second page it is.

They utilize the exact same HTML code:

```
<div id="copyright-ad">
  <p class="privacy"><a href="?page_id=295" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></p>
  <p>Copyright&#169; 2014, Touchstone Compliance LLC, All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>
```

And the exact same CSS:

```
#copyright-ad {
    clear: both;
}
#copyright p.privacy, #copyright-landing p.privacy, #copyright-ad p.privacy, #copyright-ad p, #copyright p, #copyright-landing p {
    color: #610317;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#copyright-ad p, #copyright p, #copyright-landing p {
    font-size: 0.625em;
}
#copyright a, #copyright-landing a, #copyright-ad a {
    color: #610317;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.625em;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
```

But the link does not show up on the main page!  In Firefox, if you move the cursor over to the left, you can see a hotspot there, but it's cut off at a certain point.

I'm very frustrated with this and I've tried everything.  Please help!

Thanks!
Julie

Comment: Oh my gosh.  /smacks head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the class `.ad-page-video` change the `height` to `:auto` not `400px`.

Answer (score 1):

This transparent `div` is covering the link:

```
<div class="ad-page-video">
  ...
</div>
```

Remove `height: 400px;` from `.ad-page-video` in your CSS and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

change the height in **ad-page-video** class.

It will work because your div is over the **privacy link**, so you are not able click on **privacy link**